# For $A$ any subset of vector space $X$, is it true that $A+A=2A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

It seems a trivial question:

> Prove/disprove: If we have a vector space $X$, then for any subset $A$ of $X$, we have $A+A =2A$.

It seems that $2A$ is always subset of $A+A$, but I don't think $A+A$ is subset of $2A$.

I am thinking in set of integers modulo $p$, for $p$ a prime, as a counterexample.

Am I right?

Comment: The sum is the minkowski sum?

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: The real line is a vector spave over itself. Did you try an example in this space?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A = \{v, -v\}$ for some vector $v\ne 0$.